# Nginx equivalent of “cookie prefix” from HAproxy

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

We're in the process of migrating from HAProxy to nginx. With HAProxy, we use something like this

```
cookie SESSIONID prefix
server websvr1 192.168.1.71:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie 1 check
server websvr2 192.168.1.72:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 cookie 2 check
```

This will allow client to send cooke like `1~SESSIONID` and HAProxy will strip the prefix.

Can Nginx achieve the same?